# How to limit the number of digits in input integer

Tags: java

```
String s1=sc.next();
int x=sc.nextInt();
System.out.println(s1+"\t"+x);
```

in the printing statement how to limit the number of digits for the integer, like if the input is 30 it'll print 030 is there any way to do this

Comment: Please give a better example. Your example of input 30 -> output 030 is not related to limit the number of digits in an input integer.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to limit the number of digits a user enter you could do something like this:

```
int maxDigitCount = 5; //Change this to limit amount of digits in int
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
int i = sc.nextInt();
int length = String.valueOf(i).length();
while(length > maxDigitCount) {
    i = sc.nextInt();
    length = String.valueOf(i).length();
}
sc.close();
//do something with i
```

There are other more efficient solutions to count number of digits in an integer, in this example I just choose the shortest and simplest solution as an illustration.

Answer (score 0):

```
String s1=sc.next();
int x=sc.nextInt();
String padded = String.format("%03d" , x);
System.out.println(s1+"\t\t"+padded);
```